# Android to MySQL Turkish Character Writing as "?"

Tags: php, android, mysql

When I take the EditText's text and write it to MySQL database Turkish chars are getting in the database as "?". The weird part is "ö,ü,ç" is fine. The problem is "ı" and "ğ". When i type them directly its OK too. Is my problem on Android part or PHP part, or something else?

```
        <?php



    // array for JSON response
    $response = array();

    // check for required fields
    if (isset($_POST['AdayTC'])) {

       $AdayTC = $_POST['AdayTC'];
       $OzGecmis = $_POST['OzGecmis'];
       $Projeleri = $_POST['Projeleri'];

       // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        $basvuruKontrol = mysql_query("SELECT AdayTC FROM adaybasvurusu WHERE AdayTC = '$AdayTC'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($basvuruKontrol) == 0) {
                    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO adaybasvurusu (AdayTC, OzGecmis, Projeleri, Onay) VALUES ('$AdayTC', '$OzGecmis', '$Projeleri',0)");
                        $response["success"] = 1;
                        $response["message"] = "Basvuru Gonderildi";

                        // echoing JSON response
                        echo json_encode($response);
                    } else {
                    // failed to insert row
                        $response["success"] = 0;
                        $response["message"] = "Zaten Basvuru Yapilmis";

                        // echoing JSON response
                        echo json_encode($response);
                            }

    } else {
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Gerekli Alanlar Eksik";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

**EDIT:**

I tried adding mysql_error() function:

```
 echo mysql_errno($result) . ": " . mysql_error($result) . "\n";
```

... and now i got this in my error log:

```
 [03-Jan-2014 11:43:00 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/adaybasvuru.php on line 29
```

Line 29 is the line that i add echo mysql_error function.

Comment: Could you please try executing this MySQL sentence prior to inserting those rows in it?

SET NAMES 'utf8';

Comment: Tried, nothing happened.

Comment: You should paste some significant code where you try inserting those values in the MySQL DB.

Comment: I added the PHP part, I don't think there is something to do with Android Part, am I wrong?

Comment: Your ENTIRE rendering pipeline must be the same charset, or at least connected with appropriate charset conversion logic. If you get `?` instead of expected chars, then at some point you've got a charset mismatch. client->browser->server->php->mysql->table->field and back again ALL have to match up.

Comment: That's the code you're trying? I don't see the mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") part in it. It should be executed prior to any other MySQL query.

Comment: I'm sorry i am working between 2 files now i added the  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") wrong file sorry again, now i added the other one and its not sending any values now.

Comment: If it's not inserting anything that means that there's some error in the sentence or the execution of it, you may debug it with mysql_error(). See this: http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that problem is with JSONParser class, with this i was able to solve my problem.

```
if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                StringEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"latin5");
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);


                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }
```